# Kubernetes tiller pod dying issue

Tags: linux, docker, aws, kubernetes

My kubernetes is running on top of AWS, I am using helm for templating, the problem is my `tiller pod`  keeps on dying every few hours when there is even not much load on the cluster.  I am getting no clue what so ever from logs

`ubuntu@kops:~$ kubectl get pods -owide -n kube-system  | grep tiller
tiller-deploy-6b985bb7b-88ssk                                         0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   71         19h       100.96.4.3      ip-172-20-46-194.us-west-2.compute.internal
ubuntu@kops:~$
ubuntu@kops:~$
ubuntu@kops:~$ kubectl describe pod  tiller-deploy-6b985bb7b-88ssk
Error from server (NotFound): pods "tiller-deploy-6b985bb7b-88ssk" not found
ubuntu@kops:~$
ubuntu@kops:~$
ubuntu@kops:~$
ubuntu@kops:~$
ubuntu@kops:~$ kubectl logs tiller-deploy-6b985bb7b-88ssk
Error from server (NotFound): pods "tiller-deploy-6b985bb7b-88ssk" not found
ubuntu@kops:~$`

the EC2 on which its running has a lot of free memory and CPU is 8 core load...
`admin@ip-172-20-46-194:~$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           31G       5.1G        26G       1.1M       1.5G       2.4G
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.2G        30G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B`

```
top - 03:08:29 up 19:20,  1 user,  load average: 79.51, 78.59, 77.98
Tasks: 176 total,   4 running, 172 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 28.2 us,  0.5 sy,  0.1 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si, 71.3 st
KiB Mem:  32950672 total,  5371456 used, 27579216 free,  1524240 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  2561276 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
12203 root      20   0  906520  16756   1492 S 235.0  0.1   1427:46 docker
23974 root      20   0  906520  16796   1492 S 221.1  0.1   1054:34 docker
24072 root      20   0  906520  16796   1492 S 132.0  0.1 669:17.68 docker
12318 root      20   0  906520  16792   1492 S 130.7  0.1 900:54.95 docker
17543 nobody    20   0  906520  16796   1492 S  29.1  0.1  84:01.18 docker
23865 nobody    20   0  906520  16796   1492 R  15.9  0.1  69:02.31 docker
12112 nobody    20   0  906520  16792   1492 S  14.6  0.1  91:27.51 docker
 3013 root      20   0 6753392 124600  50028 S   7.6  0.4  73:59.01 kubelet
 6378 nobody    20   0  683644 432120  29772 R   6.0  1.3  21:09.54 prometheus
```

Answer (score 0):

To get you a bit further, you need to add `--namespace kube-system` to your describe command:

```
kubectl --namespace kube-system describe pod tiller-deploy-6b985bb7b-88ssk
```

Then, you can root cause more effectively. Same if you want to try to delete the pod to get past it temporarily.